# How to dynamically change toolbar command text

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a form with a toolbar which has a 'Save' command on the right side. When the user clicks it I want it to change to 'Saved', and obviously when an alteration in the form is made I need it to revert back to the orginal 'Save' state. This should be really simple to do, but I am stuck and cannot get the command text to change; I have tried setting the text and refreshing / revalidating, but have had no luck. Thanks so much for your help.

```
           Command saveCMD = new Command("SAVE") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)           
               {                                
                  Display.getInstance().vibrate(100);
                  doSavingMethod();
                  //change command text to SAVED
               };
             };
             saveCMD.putClientProperty("uiid", "SaveCommand");
             toolbar.addCommandToRightBar(saveCMD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to address this is declaring your command as a variable and assign new values to it each time you want to change it.

```
private Command saveCMD = new Command("");

...

final Command afterSaveCmd = new Command("SAVED") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                
        //What saved command should do, if any.
    };
};

saveCMD = new Command("SAVE") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                
        Display.getInstance().vibrate(100);
        doSavingMethod();
        saveCMD = new Command("SAVED");
        //OR 
        saveCmd = afterSaveCmd;
        saveCMD.putClientProperty("uiid", "SaveCommand");
        form.removeCommand(saveCMD);
        toolbar.addCommandToRightBar(saveCMD);
        //form.revalidate();
    };
};
saveCMD.putClientProperty("uiid", "SaveCommand");
toolbar.addCommandToRightBar(saveCMD);
```

Comment: I declared both my saveCMD and afterSaveCmd commands as variables, and used: `saveCmd = afterSaveCmd;` `form.revalidate();` just like in the code you have posted, but the command text did not change. Is there something I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I managed to make it work , some extra code was needed: `form.removeCommand(saveCMD);
                    saveCMD = afterSaveCmd;
                    saveCMD.putClientProperty("uiid", "SaveCommand");
                    toolbar.addCommandToRightBar(saveCMD);
                    toolbar.revalidate();`